# How to print intermediate steps of simplifying a power formula?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, number-theory, wolfram-alpha-queries

To answer the question of [proving Fibonacci sequence is periodic mod 5 without using induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358310/#1359538)., I came across Mathematica to prove $$F_{n}\equiv F_{n+20}\pmod 5$$ for all $n \geq 2$

I defined:

$F[n] := \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\left(\cfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n-\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\left(\cfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$

and showed:

```
Simplify[f[n + 20] - f[n] - 10945 f[n] - 6765 f[n - 1]]
```

equals to 0. (I knew the fact that $F_{n+20} = 10946 F_{n}+ 6765 F_{n-1}$, but I wanted to reach a proof without induction)

Thus, for all $n \geq 2$ we have $$F_{n}\equiv F_{n+20}\pmod 5$$

The problem is that I can not get the intermediate steps of `Simplify` function, even using the [Trace commands](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TracingEvaluation.html). Could you please help?

If possible, I want to also show this in Wolfram Alpha. I don't know how to run several commands in Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: `Fibonacci[]` is built-in. Also, `Simplify[]` was never meant to show intermediate steps, as what it does under the hood is rather different from what a human would do.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. If you read my answer at math.SE, you see that I didn't want to calculate Fibonacci[n] with a reursive formula defined by induction. Because of this, I have used the closed form of Binet's formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Philippe_Marie_Binet

Comment: Yes, and `FunctionExpand[Fibonacci[n]]` will give you (a continued version of) Binet's formula. Whatever gave you the idea that `Fibonacci[]` is unsuitable here? (FWIW, I am somewhat [familiar with Binet](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A498+binet).)

Comment: Do you have any idea about how can I get the intermediate steps of simplifying?

Comment: Again: *Mathematica* does not work like that.  It doesn't do things the way a human might, so not much point in having it "show its work".

Comment: Do you mean that there is a possiblity that Mathematica does this simplifying numerically? It outputs **exact Zero**.

Comment: I am merely saying that a computer algebra system will in general not manipulate symbols in the same way a human might, nothing more.

Comment: So, I can say that my proof is mathematically correct. But I have a trouble to show others the proof. :-( Anyway, there should be a way, so I can see that how _it works_, no matter how different it does this from a human.

Comment: ["The computer is a precision tool. It should not be used as a bludgeon or a substitute for thought." - F. S. Acton](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=YHXU4W3Ez2MC&pg=PA246&dq=%22The+computer+is+a+precision+tool.%22) (See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188945).)

Comment: I don't want it to think instead of me, I want it to show the intermediate steps of simplifying an algebraic expression.